# Port Forwarding Ubuntu Server 18.04 with netplan and ufw I have a server with 2 network interfaces

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan

I have an Ubuntu server 18.04 with 2 network interfaces.

- enp1s0 has ip address 192.168.0.1/24
- enp2s0 is connected to DHCP

I am looking to forward port 8080 from any incoming traffic connected to enp2s0 to a device connected to enp1s0 which has the ip address of 192.168.0.90 on port 80.